# Remove/Hide java application from taskbar/dock

Tags: java, windows, swing, macos

When we run an java GUI application in windows or Mac, it appears in taskbar or dock as shown below.

In Windows Taskbar:

[image]

In Mac Dock:

[image]

I was wondering if there is a way to hide or remove the application from taskbar/dock. I mean the GUI application will run but it will not be shown in dock/taskbar.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the underlying reason you want to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to replace JFrame with JDialog.

Answer (score 4):

This appears to be platform dependent.

On Mac OS X, set the `Info.plist` property `LSUIElement` to 1.